# Pandas multiplying fields given a condition

Tags: python, pandas, multiplication

I have a pandas data frame like so:

```
    (Index),Field,Key,Value,Status
    5/1/2020,% Contribution| g1,Greg,0.01,Student
    5/1/2020,% Contribution| g2,Greg,0.2,Student
    5/1/2020,Amount| g1,Greg,100,Student
    5/1/2020,Amount| g2,Greg,200,Student
    5/2/2020,% Contribution| g1,Greg,0.3,Student
    5/2/2020,% Contribution| g2,Greg,0.02,Student
    5/2/2020,Amount| g1,Greg,20,Student
    5/2/2020,Amount| g2,Greg,1000,Student
    5/2/2020,% Contribution| g1,Sam,0.03,Alumni
    5/2/2020,Amount| g1,Sam,30,Alumni
    5/2/2020,% Contribution| g2,Karl,0.06,Student
    5/2/2020,Amount| g2,Karl,100,Student
```

What I want is given a Status to multiply Fields that have the g1  string in them together and similarly for g2. So on say 5/1/20 for the Status "Student" I would like to filter on the key Greg, multiply the g1 fields together, multiply the g2 fields together and then add up the total: .01 * 100+.2 * 200 = 41. For 5/2 I want to do the same, but we have an entry for Karl as well, Sam is ignored since he is an alumni. I am so bad at pandas I am filtering on specific fields, extracting explicit cells then multiplying those numbers together, but it is so messy I have to assume there is a better way. What I would like my output to be is:

```
    index,Agg_value,Key,Status
    5/1/20,41,Greg,Student
    5/2/20,26,Greg,Student
    5/2/20,6,Karl,Student
```

For note Karl only contributes to g2 on 5/2 not g1, and there will never be a case in which % Contribution| g1 is populated for a person, but Amount| g1 is not simultaneously populated. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, your question is a little bit confusing. I tried to help in the answer but not 100% sure if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Apologies for not being clearer, I think part of the issue is that "*" was being hidden in my multiplication. Anyway the code below references columns G1/G2, which literally do not exist. I have a column Field, that column contains entries that are strings that contain substrings "g1" and "g2." that is what I am trying to multiply together; the Values that have a Field entry that contains those substrings. I cannot even pivot my table due to my index containing multiple entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy where to create a new column in your dataframe with a condition. [Here is the link for the documentation.](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

The code would be something like this: `df["Calc"] = numpy.where(df["Status"] == "Student", df["G1"] * df["G2], 0)`